# Judged By Treating Wife

Tags: sources-mekorot, marriage

Rabbi Tzoren [quotes](https://www.hidabroot.com/article/192598/The-Measure-of-a-Man-is-How-He-Treats-His-Wife) Alenu L'Shabeach who quotes Rav Chaim Vital saying

> A man’s character is measured only by how he treats his wife!

Where does Rav Chaim Vital say this?